# 'How to read a file content until 'n' occurrences of a character and write it into a variable", using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a text file that is being written by Apache Flink Tool.
1. I want to extract this file's contents until it encounters the 999th "},"
2. Delete the last comma(,)
3. Add "[" and "]" at the beginning and end of the read content.
4. Write this modified content into a variable.

All of these are to be written into a variable.

Is the entire operation possible through Javascript?

The purpose of this action is to make it resemble an JSON array used to plot Highcharts that can load upto 1000 points only, at once.

Contents of txt file Flink is writing into:

```
{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371996","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171424","timestamp2":"1493270171454","timestamp3":"1493270171454"},
{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137112","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171522","timestamp3":"1493270171523"},
{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371186","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171523","timestamp3":"1493270171524"},
{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371595","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171524","timestamp3":"1493270171525"},
{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137168","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529"},
{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371684","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529"},
```

The (JSON) format in which the contents are to be written after all the above listed actions are performed:

```
[
    {
        "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371996",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1493270171424",
        "timestamp2": "1493270171454",
        "timestamp3": "1493270171454"
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "28.48908469137112",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1493270171426",
        "timestamp2": "1493270171522",
        "timestamp3": "1493270171523"
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "28.489084691371186",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1493270171426",
        "timestamp2": "1493270171523",
        "timestamp3": "1493270171524"
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes it is possible with Javascript.So, what you have tried so far ?
Show the code .

Comment: FYI: Highcharts can load up to millions of points at once. To load more than 1k, start with setting [`series.turboThreshold`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's that, that will return an array that looks like this:

```
[
    [
        {999 ENTRIES}
    ],
    [
        {999 MORE ENTRIES}
    ]
    ...
]
```

```js
var input = '{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371996","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171424","timestamp2":"1493270171454","timestamp3":"1493270171454"}\n{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137112","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171522","timestamp3":"1493270171523"}\n{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371186","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171523","timestamp3":"1493270171524"}\n{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371595","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171426","timestamp2":"1493270171524","timestamp3":"1493270171525"}\n{"temperSensorData":"28.48908469137168","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529"}\n{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371684","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270171428","timestamp2":"1493270171529","timestamp3":"1493270171529"}'

splitInput = input.split('\n')
output = splitInput.map((item) => {
  return JSON.parse(item)
})

splitOutput = []

var chunk = 999;
for (var i=0,j=output.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    splitOutput.push(output.slice(i,i+chunk))
}

console.log(splitOutput)
```

Comment: Can you exclude the outer square brackets and update your answer? I only need one set of square brackets outside of my {..},{..},{..},...{..} elements :)

Comment: Also, you have manually added "\n" after each "}". This is not possible in real-time to manually go and change the txt file's content as Flink is continuously writing into the txt file. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: The reason as to why those outer brackets are there is because if you split the list at every 999 items, you will have multiple lists of 999 entries, and where would you store those lists? the easiest thing would be to store them in another list like what I've done. that way if you want the outer brackets gone you just access the first list `splitOutput[0]` or the second list `splitOutput[1]`

Comment: in regards to the manually adding \n. a new line is represented by either `\n` or `\r` so if flink is creating new lines, it isn't actually creating a new line, rather it is putting in the character `\n` or `\r`

Comment: Sorry, but i missed adding the commas following every {..} element (here in the post) as written by Flink into txt file. You mean to tell you didnt edit the structure to include "\n" while writing into a variable?

Comment: is the flink file also wrapped in `[` `]` tags? should be an easy change, just need to know all of the parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142907/discussion-between-inchara-raveendra-and-anis-jonischkeit).